# Changing data source file path?

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, arcgis-10.5

I have little experience in scripting and I'm looking for a more efficient way  to replace the source file path of over 1000 shape files.

Is there a way I can do this without manually changing each file path?

As an example: I need to replace the S1 to S2 in the following file path

```
H:\GQRA screening tool\Shapefiles\S1 SOLID Ali _C10-12 0.5 m
```

this is the script i'm using, however the bit im struggling with is how to replace a partial string section of the file path.

```
import arcpy  
... mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(r"H:\GQRA screening 
tool\Arcmap\SwecoTemplate_SI_A3_S2.mxd")  
... for lyr in arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd):  
...     if lyr.supports("DATASOURCE"):  
...         if lyr.dataSource == r"H:\GQRA screening tool\Shapefiles":  
...             lyr.findAndReplaceWorkspacePath(r"S1", r"S2")  
... mxd.saveACopy(r"H:\GQRA screening tool\Arcmap\SwecoTemplate_SI_A3_New")  
... del mxd
```

This is the updated script, however still not got it right yet.

```
import arcpy  
... mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(r"H:\GQRA screening 
tool\Arcmap\SwecoTemplate_SI_A3_S2.mxd")  
... for lyr in arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd):  
...     if lyr.supports("DATASOURCE"):  
...         if r"H:\GQRA screening tool\Shapefiles":  
...             lyr.findAndReplaceWorkspacePath(r"S1", r"S2")  
... mxd.saveACopy(r"H:\GQRA screening tool\Arcmap\SwecoTemplate_SI_A3_New")  
... del mxd
```

Comment: At least for QGIS projects of the uncompressed `.qgs` format can be opened in any proper text editor (e.g Notepad++) and edited. Especially you may use `ctrl+H` to find and replace relevant passages of text/code.
Note on the side: Spaces in filepaths may lead to problems.

Comment: This is a simple task with Python/ArcPy, but it requires coding. I would urge you to re-evaluate your directory naming scheme -- spaces in directory paths are a disaster waiting to happen.

Comment: Thanks, not working with my own data hence the spaces, i can can rid of these in the next iteration of the data model.

Comment: `lyr.dataSource` is the full path to a feature class (not a folder). I think your test should be more like `if r"H:\GQRA screening tool\Shapefiles" in lyr.dataSource:`

Comment: @Andy has nailed it, `dataSource` is the full path so your test is failing.

Comment: Guys, sorry for my lack of knowledge but which parts should i be replacing?

Answer (score 1):

Try this (untested):

```
import arcpy  
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(r"H:\GQRA screening tool\Arcmap\SwecoTemplate_SI_A3_S2.mxd")  
for lyr in arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd):  
    if lyr.supports("DATASOURCE"):  
        if r"h:\gqra screening tool\shapefiles" in lyr.dataSource.lower():  
            lyr.findAndReplaceWorkspacePath(r"S1", r"S2")  
mxd.saveACopy(r"H:\GQRA screening tool\Arcmap\SwecoTemplate_SI_A3_New")  
del mxd
```

You may find that you need to modify or even simplify the test `if xxx in lyr.dataSource`. One common way you would modify it is to account for differences in case by converting both sides to lowercase, as I've done here. As @Vince noted above, spaces in the file paths could be troublesome. I'd probably look to test for only "GQRA," or somthing like that, if I could get away with it.